# find or locate Windows Server 2008 R2 volume license key

Tags: windows, keys, finder

Need help to find and locate Windows Server 2008 R2 volume license keys from the system registry, to document what keys are with which server. I have tried Magic Jelly Bean and Produkey, but both will not display "volume license keys", but instead either display nothing, or all BBBB-BBBBB...'s

If anyone knows of a way to retrieve the product key, or through a known working 3rd party utility it would be life saver.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that with Server 2008 the original Volume License Key isn't actually stored in the registry.  To retrieve them you'll need the original purchasing account for the [Microsoft Volume Licensing Service Center](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx).

Comment: Rumour has it that Microsoft don't care *that much* about which of your keys you use, as long as you have enough licenses to cover all your installations, and you have documented that you have a license for each install.